# Android - relative layout image over at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I fix  this. I want to the half of the image be inside of the top one.

**Actually:**

[image]

**Xml Code :**

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gmaps_image_test"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_coffee"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/category_image"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

And this is what i cant do.. Is there any atttribute missing?

**My Output :**

[image]

Comment: post your whole layout

Comment: increase the height of your relative layout to 275dp.

Comment: Can you post an image what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Main `RelativeLayout` height to `275dp` and give negetive margin to `ImageView`.

Add this way

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="275dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gmaps_image_test"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_coffee"
    android:layout_below="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"/>
```

Comment: @Dex Sebas glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
```

Try  margin with negative value.

Answer (score 0):

Change layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="275dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gmaps_image_test"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_coffee"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Some things changed: 
layout_height of RelativeLayout 275dp

```
android:layout_height="275dp"
```

and of second ImageView.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using negative margin can mess up when dealing with different screen sizes, Its better to go for Coordinator layout, it has something called **layout_anchor** which anchors whatever you want to attach and you can specify the position in **layout_anchorGravity**.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gmaps_image_test"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_coffee"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/category_image"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```